ASP.NET MVC / Razor : using date picker with string field
I have the following "date" fields in my model that are representing as a string:


I have the following in my view:


My question is how do I get cast the string properly to fit the date picker?
I'm not sure if it should be done in the Model or View.

WHY are you storing dates as strings? Use the most appropriate datatype - always - no exceptions. This is just asking or headaches and lots of messy code down the line ....

I don't have control over the table.

@H22 Even so, you can still use DateOnly or DateTime in your application-code.

@H22 Also, using = null! with a non-nullable String property's initializer is just wrong. If a property can be null then it should be typed as String? and reference-types  don't need initializing to null because it's implicit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1805 . - what your code is doing right-now is sabotaging itself and hiding the evidence of sabotage under the rug.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

My pontifical points are in no particular permutation:

Do not use String when a better value-type is available.

In this case, you should use DateOnly? (a.k.a. Nullable<DateOnly>).

Nullable<T> should be used because it allows for empty date inputs, which <input type="date" value="" /> allows, whereas a non-nullable DateOnly view-model property is harder to work with when using ASP.NET's model-binding because any form field can be empty or invalid - or just plain undefined. You might think that the [Required] attribute solves this problem but it doesn't: the [Required] attribute doesn't stop a property being empty, it just stops ModelStateDictionary.IsValid returning true when a property is empty, which means you will always need to correctly (if not gracefully) handle empty/undefined form fields and differentiate that from whatever the default(T) of a value-type is (e.g. default(DateOnly) is .


Even though your underlying database is unfortunately storing dates incorrectly, that doesn't stop you from using appropriate types in your application code.

If you're using EF entity classes generated from your existing DB then that's no excuse because you should not be using EF entity classes with ASP.NET Form Binding, instead you should define a separate class MyPageViewModel, which can expose the data as DateOnly?-typed properties.




HTML <input type="date" /> requires that the value="" parameter be formatted as yyyy-MM-dd.
ASP.NET's HTML-Helpers are effectively obsolete thesedays, consider using Tag-Helpers instead:

Use <input asp-for="YMDEFF" type="date" /> instead of Html.TextBoxFor.

The asp-for="" is a special ModelExpression attribute just like TextBoxFor's Expression<> parameter and it's used to generate the id="" and name="" attributes at runtime.




For the love of program-correctness, please never do public String SomeProperty { get; set; } = null! - it's just wrong on so many levels.

If a String property can ever be null then its type must be String? - not String - and the initialization to null is just redundant.
If a String property will never be null then initialize it to = String.Empty or = "", not null!, yikes.


Do not use all-caps names like YMDEFF and YMDEND - in C#/.NET we use PascalCase and camelCase such that all words and acronyms 3 letters or longer are always TitleCase, while all 2-letter initialisms are always uppercase (like IO) while 2-letter abbreviations (like Db for "Database") are not.

Now YMDEFF looks like "YMD Eff...", I assume YMD refers to the date-format and that "Eff" is short for "Effective", so just named it EffectiveDate.
And YMDEND looks like "YMD End", by the same logic this should be named EndDate.



Like so:
public class MyPageViewModel
{
//  [Required] // <-- Uncomment or delete this line, based on your actual requirements.
    [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true )] // <-- This attribute is necessary to ensure the `<input value=""/>` attribute has the correct format that HTML requires.
    public DateOnly? EffectiveDate { get; set; }

//  [Required]
    [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true )]
    public DateOnly? EndDate { get; set; }
}

Your Razor markup could look like this:
@model MyPageViewModel

// etc

<form asp-controller="Foobar" asp-action="PostForm">

    <div class="field">
        <label asp-for="EffectiveDate"></label>
        <input asp-for="EffectiveDate" type="date" />
        <span asp-validation-for="EffectiveDate"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label asp-for="EndDate"></label>
        <input asp-for="EndDate" type="date" />
        <span asp-validation-for="EndDate"></span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

Your Controller Action would hold the logic for marshaling between your database's (abominable) String-based dates and DateOnly dates:
public sealed class FoobarController : Controller
{

    [Route( "/my-form" )] // <-- Use [Route] for GET actions instead of [HttpGet] because it means ASP.NET can handle HEAD, and other request verbs, for you automagically.
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetForm()
    {
        SomeEntityClass? e = await this.db.GetThingAsync();
        if( e is null ) return this.NotFound();

        MyPageViewModel vm = new MyPageViewModel()
        {
            EffectiveDate = DateOnly.TryParseExact( s: e.YMDEFF, format: "yyyyMMdd", provider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, style: 0, out DateOnly parsed1 ) ? parsed1 : (DateOnly?)null,
            EndDate       = DateOnly.TryParseExact( s: e.YMDEND, format; "yyyyMMdd", provider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, style: 0, out DateOnly parsed2 ) ? parsed2 : (DateOnly?)null
        };

        return this.View( model: vm );
    }

    [HttpPost( "/my-form" )]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostForm( [FromForm] MyPageViewModel model )
    {
        SomeEntityClass? e = await this.db.GetThingAsync();
        if( e is null ) return this.NotFound();

        if( !this.ModelState.IsValid ) return this.View( model: model );
        Debug.Assert( model.EffectiveDate.HasValue ); // <-- This is to workaround how the C# compiler isn't aware that `ModelState.IsValid` indicates (for example) non-nullability of those View-Model properties.
        Debug.Assert( model.EndDate.HasValue );

        //

        e.YMDEFF = model.EffectiveDate.Value.Tostring( format: "yyyyMMdd" );
        e.YMDEND = model.EndDate      .Value.Tostring( format: "yyyyMMdd" );

        await this.db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return this.RedirectToAction( nameof(GetForm) );
    }

}



Following your "For the love of program-correctness" gives me "possible null reference assignment" in my service class.
EffectiveDate = DateOnly.TryParseExact( format; "yyyyMMdd", value: e.YMDEFF, out DateOnly parsed1 ) ? parsed1 : (DateOnly?)null, is not valid for .NET 6 or 8???
SomeEntityClass? e = await this.db.GetThingAsync(); ...So I'm getting the data from the database (string from DB to DateOnly in the model) and then I'm converting the fields to a DateOnly again?


@H22 re point 1: that means you've got a null-correctness issue in your service-class.

@H22 re point 2: the code I posted is not meant to be copied-and-pasted literally (which is why I wrote "...look like this"), but I'll correct that now.

@H22 re point 3: the SomeEntityClass is just an example - your post didn't say where/how you got those values from your database so I had to make assumptions. I can adjust my answer to suit your situation but only if you add those details to your question post, which you haven't yet done.

I was able to get the datatype changed to date in the database. Thanks for your help. Should I delete the question?

@H22 Please don't.
